# Check how to access the array elements in Angular 5 HTML

Tags: arrays, angular, html, typescript, angular5

if array of elements like A and B in typescript file, how to check whether the A is present

Comment: <div *ngIf = "..."></div>

Comment: Array =['A','B']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a property like `arr` and it value like this

```
arr = ['A','B'];
```

template

```
<div *ngIf="arr && arr.indexOf('A') !== -1"> ... </div>
```

or

```
<p *ngIf="arr && arr.length > 0 && arr.includes('A')">...</p>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqqjvr)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the includes() method

```
<div *ngIf="['A','B'].includes('A')"></div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dykag4)